# Case condition broken need assistance to fix

Tags: sql, sql-server

New to SQL, so please accept my apologies. A query was created that when

```
If HBL_CLNT_CAT._HS_EB_CODE1 = 'BF' then value = TBM_BILLGRP._HS_EB_DET1
If HBL_CLNT_CAT._HS_EB_CODE2 = 'BF' then value = TBM_BILLGRP._HS_EB_DET2
```

However of the `_HS_EB_DET#` exceeds 100 characters add a '*'.

With assistance a query was developed, however it broken the condition rules in that the 'then statement/action would fail because it was greater number than the condition statement (`select _hs_eb_code1 from hbl_cat where hs_eb_code = 'bf'` that returns only 1 record).

```
select
  case when len(format) > 100
       then left(format, 100) + '*'
       else format 
 end as format
from
  ( select 
      case when exists ( select _hs_eb_code1
                         from hbl_cat 
                         where hs_eb_code = 'bf'
                       )
           then tbm_bllgrp._hs_eb_det1 
      end
   ) as format 
     from tbm_bllgrp
```

Comment: Doesn't it make sense to add a UNIQUE constraint to hbl_cat? Then it will fail when duplicates ares inserted, not when they are selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting the code would have helped you find the error. Try this:

```
select
  case when len(format) > 100
       then left(format, 100) + '*'
       else format 
  end as format
from
  ( select 
      case when exists ( select _hs_eb_code1
                         from hbl_cat 
                         where hs_eb_code = 'bf'
                       )
           then tbm_bllgrp._hs_eb_det1 
      end as format 
     from tbm_bllgrp 
  ) as tmp
```

Comment: But it seems your query is not using the `TBM_BILLGRP._HS_EB_DET2` you mention in the description. Neither does it use any relationship between the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

The above query is broken in several places. A working statement could look like this:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN len(x.myval) > 100 THEN
        left(x.myval,100) + '*'
    ELSE
        x.myval
    END AS format
 FROM (
    SELECT CASE
            WHEN h.HS_EB_CODE1 = 'BF' THEN
                t._HS_EB_DET1
            WHEN h._HS_EB_CODE2 = 'BF' THEN
                t._HS_EB_DET2
            ELSE
                'unknown option'
            END AS myval
      FROM HBL_CLNT_CAT AS h
      JOIN TBM_BILLGRP AS t ON  ???  -- how are the two tables connected?
     WHERE ??? -- some condition or do you want all rows in the table?
        ) AS x
```

But you need to tell us first, how TBM_BILLGRP and HBL_CLNT_CAT can be joined, and how you select your rows.
BTW, upper case is pointless in SQL-Server. Identifiers are case-insensitive as long as they are not enclosed in double quotes `" "` or brackets `[ ]`.

Comment: PostgreSQL? He has sql-server tag.

Comment: @ypercube: Thank you! I corrected that. Normally, SQL-Server has case-insensitive identifiers, too. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)